# User manuel not showing for uploaded extension in TYPO3 repository

Tags: typo3-6.2.x, typo3-extensions

I have created some extensions for typo3 and added it to [TYPO3 Extension Respository](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/)

But after uploading and checked through out to see the "manuel" added along with it as a "link". But it showing like

```
Manual  :  Not available
```

One of my extension contain only `manuel.sxw` file in `doc/` folder
and one of it contain `wizard_form.html` and `wizard_form.dat` in it. But no use.
Please any one help. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check these things in your documentation

1. **Correct the Index of Document**
2. **Double check the page number in indexing**
3. Give proper headings
4. Correct the alignment of document
5. **Highlight indexed headings than other text content**

try this

Thankz

Comment: Thank u.. I already found it. Your ans  will be helpful for others having same issue.